# Android error 400 for Google App Scripts API in one particular phone only

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android app which uses Google Apps scripts API. It used to work well in my phone. But one day suddenly it keeps showing the error

```
400. That’s an error.

The server cannot process the request because it is malformed. It should not be retried. That’s all we know.
```

Below are the screen shots [image]

The URL shown in browser which shows 400 Error is

https://myaccount.google.com/accounts/SetOSID?authuser=0&continue=https://myaccount.google.com/?utm_source%3Dsign_in_no_continue%26pli%3D1&osidt=ALWU2cuuoBlBDhPdnwXk6R88QyROZeBJ5TvpUX-a7kVFgenCFZIs8mu989e_H_UOydqthw5-s2MbCHUB_GJygjJEZYjLJkJ5bEN0wy5XDfKYDrCSL9nPuxQPy7aM4nhn-THMy6pmeuOCY82juRZruR4O8E5VMmv-NvGhZneWm62pHJafv82hXlxOTnW4DKNUBrWPZ_gqrb89AfOl8xoT8_YOw7JeiK1wMYUIWCBng6MbDYxBZnnvZOQ&ifkv=AYZoVhfaadmcvQcQTU3-kXQzP3mgOILJLTXdXUk33L4-3wd4gWJNb7ufxjJRo9kED_jzDl-Tyk_8

The error pops up when i start activity to confirm user consent (NeedRemoteConsent)

```
if (mLastError instanceof UserRecoverableAuthIOException) {
                currentFragment.getActivity().startActivityForResult(
                        ((UserRecoverableAuthIOException) mLastError).getIntent(),
                        GoogleAppScriptsHelper.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
            }
```

Strangely it works flawlessly in other phones when tested.

If anyone knows the solution please help

I have cleared

1. Data and Cache ,
2. Uninstalled the app and re installed
3. Restarted phone

All of no use
I am not getting any clue on how I could fix this.